# How to make a foreign key?

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys

How can I specify a foreign key in hibernate ?

I have a table `A` that has `id` as a column which also forms its primary key. Now the second table `B` also has `id` as the column but it should be the `foreign key` that references the `id` column of `table A`.

How can I specify this relation ?

Answer (score 0):

This example is a one to one relation using shared primary key.
You can use @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn to achieve this.

In Class A

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID")
public B getB() {
    return b;
}
```

In Class B,

```
@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "foreign", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "property", value = "a") })
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}


@OneToOne(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public B getB() {
    return b;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me without using annotation

Comment: Check this http://hibernate-samples.blogspot.com/2011/10/one-to-one-association-using-shared.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using annotations you must add the relation and the join column with annotations like these:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
public A getA() {
//...
}
```

if you're using a mapping xml file it's something like this:

```
<set name="objects" lazy="true" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="ID" />
    <one-to-many class="com.objectx.A" />
</set>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me without using annotation

Comment: won't it lead to automatic update of table `b` (that has foreign key) when object `a` is committed ?

Comment: This setting is for B side. If you don't want a cascade on the A side, just omit it.